# SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer

Tags: android, http, jsoup

I have a simple code and there is an exception coming, can't figure out why?
My code:

```
Document document= Jsoup.connect("https://kolkatatrafficpolice.net/").get();
```

Stack trace:

```
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:235)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:247)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:571)
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:548)
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:235)
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:224)
W/System.err:     at com.pritesh.trafficviolation.GetHtml.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:29)
```

Answer (score 0):

That server is using an unrecognized certificate authority.

If this is your server, and you are intentionally doing this (e.g., this is a self-signed certificate), you would need to configure JSoup/OkHttp to use that self-signed certificate.

Otherwise, your problems lie with the server.

Comment: its not my server, i just have one line of code nothing else. How can I solve this.

Comment: @Pritesh: Switch to a different server, one that uses a recognized root certificate authority. Or, see if you can find some tools that let you find out what the root certificate authority is that they are using, then use [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html), my [backport](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-netsecurity) of that, or your own custom `TrustManager`, to try to teach JSoup/OkHttp to honor that root certificate.